# Position background image - x from top and x from bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, background-image

http://jsfiddle.net/sXLg7/1/

I am trying to place the background image such that there is 50px space left at the top and bottom of the div.

I can position background image easily 50px below top by this property

```
background-position: 0 50px;
```

But, how do i also position this background image so that there is 50px space lefft at the bottom

I tried this

```
 background-position: 0 50px 0 50px;
```

but this doesn't seem to work. I assumed it would accept 4 parameters for positioning it from 4 directions.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the background-clip property instead :

```
padding-top:50px;
padding-bottom:50px;
background-clip: content-box;
```

See this Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/A5u8j/

Comment: This works, and it is the ideal solution i was looking for. Thank you very much Dude :)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I do not believe this is possible. Depending on what it's being used for, you might be able to use two divs, with the inner div having the background image and a top & bottom margin of 50px;

Answer (score 1):

try adding this two properties

```
background-size: 500px 400px;
background-position: 0 50px;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with background position; however, you could hack something together using a pseudo-element.

http://jsfiddle.net/sXLg7/3/

Here is the updated CSS:

```
.test {
    border: 2px solid red;
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    position: relative;
}
.test:before {
    content: '';
    z-index: -1;
    background-image: url("http://www.reallyslick.com/pictures/helios.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS [`background-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size), although [browser support is somewhat limited](http://caniuse.com/#feat=background-img-opts).

```css
.test {
    border: 2px solid red;
    background-image: url("http://www.reallyslick.com/pictures/helios.jpg");
    background-position: 0 50px;
    background-size:100% 400px;
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/sXLg7/2/)

---

### Alternate Method

Alternately, you can use two nested elements. The outer has padding set on the top and bottom to so that the inner won't reach the top/bottom.

I've used CSS [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) so that the padding is accounted for in the height. Note that support for this is also [somewhat limited](http://caniuse.com/css3-boxsizing).

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/sXLg7/4/)

---

Alternatively, you can subtract the padding from the height of the outer element.

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/sXLg7/6/)

Answer (score 1):

Heres one way todo it. Place an image with absolute positioning, and a negative z-index. Places it behind any content in your test div.

http://jsfiddle.net/sXLg7/8/

html

```
<div class="test">
    Text on top of background.
    <img src="http://www.reallyslick.com/pictures/helios.jpg" class="background"/>
</div>
```

and the css

```
.test {    
border: 2px solid red;
height: 500px;
width: 500px;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
color: #fff;
}

.test .background {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 50px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could put a 50px border on the element.

http://jsfiddle.net/sXLg7/10/

html

```
<div class="test"></div>
```

css

```
.test {
  outline: 2px solid red;
  border: 50px solid transparent;
  background-image: url("http://www.reallyslick.com/pictures/helios.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-size: auto 100%;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

why not just add a 50px margin? like this:

```
.test {

    border: 2px solid red;
    background-image: url("http://www.reallyslick.com/pictures/helios.jpg");
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin:50px;

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4Dmkv/

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. But, i want this image to have that white space left at the bottom. I am actually doing lot more complex than it seems. i am using a background image for my timeline made using d3 library

Comment: oh I see. so will your div always be the same size or will it change sizes depending on the window size?

Comment: The div size is not fixed. It will change depending on the data rendered inside and the screen size and the device.